# Spring Batch Retry - does Spring start where it left off or start from beginning

Tags: java, spring-batch

Below is my config for re-try:

```
    <batch:job id="myLookUpLoadJob">   
          <batch:step id="myLookUpTruncateStep">
                 <batch:tasklet ref="myLookupTruncateTasklet" />
                 <batch:next on="*" to="myLookUpLoadStep"/>
          </batch:step> 
          <batch:step id="myLookUpLoadStep">               
                 <batch:tasklet>
                       <batch:chunk reader="myLookupItemReader"
                              writer="myLookupItemWriter" commit-interval="100" retry-limit="2">
                               <retryable-exception-classes>
                                        <include class=" org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException"/>
                              </retryable-exception-classes>
                       </batch:chunk>
                 </batch:tasklet>           
          </batch:step>
   </batch:job>
```

Below are my questions for which I am not able to get answers from Spring doc - would appreciate input:

When an exception occurs after processing 200 rows when retry happens does it start from row 201 or from row1?

**Edit**

The problem I am trying to solve is that when the job runs, immediately after the commit of first chunk (100 rows), the connection to the ItemReader gets terminated (reset).  The job is then re-started and it completes successfully.

I am wondering if this might help:

**From AbstractCursorItemReader**

*There is an option (setUseSharedExtendedConnection(boolean) that will share the connection used for the cursor with the rest of the step processing. If you set this flag to true then you must wrap the DataSource in a ExtendedConnectionDataSourceProxy to prevent the connection from being closed and released after each commit performed as part of the step processing. You must also use a JDBC driver supporting JDBC 3.0 or later since the cursor will be opened with the additional option of 'HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT' enabled.*

Comment: What reader are you using?

Comment: org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader.  Also the read and write are against 2 different data sources which is why initially I thought of pursuing XA distributed transactions.

Comment: @MichaelMinella - did you have any update?  I am planning on testing restart early next week (since we have a deploy this week).  The doc re UseSharedExtendedConnection in the AbstractCursorItemReader seems tempting to try.

Comment: If you are using an old JDBC driver, definitely upgrade so that the flag can be set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on your reader.  `ItemReader` implementations are responsible for persisting their own state in the `ExecutionContext` via the `ItemStream` interface callbacks.  If the `ItemReader` has persisted it's state (row number I'd assume in this case) via the `ItemStream#update` method and if the `ItemReader` restores that state via the `ItemSteam#open` callback method, then I'd expect it to restart at the correct row.  All of the Spring provided `ItemReader` implementations utilize this functionality where it makes sense.  I just can't tell if yours will since I don't have any insight into what the `myLookupItemReader` is in your configuration.

Comment: Thanks @Michael for the detailed reply.  I am using Spring's implementation of the ItemReader - JdbcCursorItemReader and therefore the default behavior should work.  One more question - would retry work the same way?

Comment: Edited the question - added more details